# Is there a nice one-liner to provide a default if a value is None?

Tags: python, null-coalescing

There is a possibility that I am searching under wrong keywords, but I can't find the answer to the question:

Is there a nice one-liner to provide a default value if the variable is NoneType?

For example:

```
def validate_quantity(self, value):
        instance = self.instance
        diff = value - instance.quantity
```

results in error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'NoneType'

I know dictionaries have a `.get()` method which works like that:

```
smth.get('quantity', 200)
```

but it cannot be applied to an object instance.

This:

```
diff = value - (instance.quantity or 0)
```

does not work either because it returns 0 when `instance.quantity` is `None`, but also when it is `[]` or `""`.

Comment: This doesn't make a great deal of sense. If instance.quantity is either [] or "" then surely you would want some kind of default or, even better, raise an exception because instance.quantity is expected to be Decimal. If it's a list or a string then something's gone terribly wrong

Comment: This is just an example. The asker is looking for a general solution.

Comment: @user3840170 The question is very specific around NoneType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the walrus operator, introduced in Python 3.8 ([PEP 572](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/)):

```
diff = value - (0 if (q := instance.quantity) is None else q)
```

To me, it looks at best moderately readable (you can also try swapping ‘then’ and ‘else’ parts, i.e. `q if (q := instance.quantity) is not None else 0`, if you prefer), but it has the advantage that it only evaluates `instance.quantity` once, and does not evaluate the fallback expression if not needed.

There have been proposals to introduce a proper `None`-coalescing operator (see [PEP 505](https://peps.python.org/pep-0505/)), but there is currently no consensus to add one to the language.  The LWN article [‘Not coalescing around None-aware’](https://lwn.net/Articles/918058/) covers some discussions.

Comment: Isn't this functionally equivalent to *diff = value - (0 if instance.quantity is None else instance.quantity)* ? And, if so, what is the benefit of the assignment expression?

Comment: @Pingu Read the answer again.

Comment: I read it. So you're saying that the evaluation of instance.quantity is potentially more expensive than the instantiation of *q*. I guess that's your point. Fair enough

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
diff = value - (instance.quantity if not isinstance(instance.quantity, type(None)) else Decimal(1000))
```

...where Decimal(1000) is your default value and the *isinstance()* test is specific for NoneType (as per the question)